# How to limit FPS in pyglet? (window on_draw event)

Tags: python, frame-rate, pyglet

My pyglet application works fine, but I feel that the FPS I'm getting is excessively high and just unnecessary CPU usage for my needs. I'm getting FPS that seems to range from 200-2000, when I really only need about 60.

In older versions of pyglet there is a function called `set_fps` and all the existing help online seems to point to this deprecated function I can't use.

The pyglet docs now say that to limit stuff you should use the `pyglet.clock.schedule_interval` function, which I do already use for my `update` method to allow it to be called 60 times a second: `pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(update, 1 / 60.0)`. This works. But I need to somehow do the same for my `on_draw` event of my window. Scheduling this doesn't seem possible.

Does anyone know how to limit the FPS in pyglet?

My code isn't so different from the [example game](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/programming_guide/examplegame.html) in pyglet's documentation.

```
window = pyglet.window.Window()

@window.event
def on_draw():  # <----- how to limit how often this is called?
    # ... perform ordinary window drawing operations ...
```

---

Edit:

After bumbling around for a while I found a solution, maybe, but unsure if this is the correct way to do it:

```
def draw_everything(dt):
    # draw stuff here

@window.event
def on_draw():
    draw_everything(None)

pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(draw_everything, 1/60)
```

Comment: That is the correct way of doing it :)

Comment: @Torxed Wouldn't this call `draw_everything` 60 times per second *and* whenever the window calls `on_draw`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the correct way of doing it is like this:

```
def draw_everything(dt):
# draw stuff here

@window.event
def on_draw():
    draw_everything(None)

pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(draw_everything, 1/60)
```

Comment: Is there a way to vary the schedule_interval while executing? ie. can I trigger a change in the schedule_interval from a key press event? that way the user can change the frame rate using the keyboard?